# Will Nvidia be supported in Natty Narwhal with Unity

Tags: unity, nvidia

I have been trying to get Natty running on my desktop pc with a Nvidia 8400GS card but not having much luck.
I can see on the forums that it is related to the X server version and the nvidia driver.
Will i be able to install 11.04 with Unity desktop using my Nvidia card?

Comment: Please see: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate

Comment: As Jorge and Alaukik have both said, this is speculative about something that is far from finished and is a bug. Track this on Launchpad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natty is in alpha state and recently an xserver update changed its abi so the current nvdia drivers don't work and there is an bug in the floss drivers.

But i am quite sure that the drivers will be updated and even the floss driver's bug will be fixed so you will be able to use 11.04 on 28 April.